# How to work with gulp via FTP?

Tags: html, wordpress, ftp, gulp

First of all, I'm sorry if this is pretty stupid question for you, I was searching the web for the answer, but unfortunately couldn't find complex one.

Recently I discovered not so new, but still cool stuff like SCSS, Pug, LiveReload, Gulp and all that automation stuff. I was really blown away, cause I've been like in a cave for past 2-3 years. So, the development for me is pretty easy and fast now, but I've got problem with production of this.

So, for example, I have to develop WordPress site. One year ago, I'd just run local server, install WordPress there, then I create a new template and customize it for customer needs. After that, I'd upload all of that on web-server (for FTP stuff I use Filezilla, if there's better tools - point me, please) and than, if needed, I'd open desired files from "Edit" menu in Filezilla, customize them, save - and that it's done, I can see the result in browser. I don't need local copy of the web-site on my computer (since some web-sites nowadays are pretty 'heavy').

Now, I don't know what to do with that automation stuff, cause it's all running with console and has to be compiled. So, in order to develop complex CMS-driven web-sites using automation tools, I need to always have latest copy on my local machine, and that send it again on web-server? What if customer, for example, decides to change the article or something on the web-site, when I sync my local copy with web-server, it'll be lost.

So, my main question, is there a way for me to create WordPress website using Gulp & Co and then **easily** update it later, via FTP client?

Comment: "What if customer, for example, decides to change the article or something on the web-site, when I sync my local copy with web-server, it'll be lost" — You're not supposed to reinstall WordPress from scratch with a clean database every time you change the theme.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But still it doesn't answer the question

Comment: That's why it was posted as a comment, not an answer.